# 'Oracle.DataAccess.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'

Tags: .net, oracle, deployment

I am receiving the following error shown in the Title, when i create a MSI Package.

My Environment of project is

1. Project uses 32 bit visual studio
2. oracle client is 64 bit.

can i still may the msi project to work using the above environment.. if yes how can i do it

Answer (score 1):

I would switch to the 32-bits client. If you are supposed to generate 32-bits code, you need the 32-bits client libs. With a little luck they are installed together with the 64-bits client, if that is the case they are in ORACLE_HOME/lib32/ and in that case you could try using LIBRARY_PATH settings pointing to the lib32 directory.
It is not very important to what kind of database you connect, 32-bits or 64-bits server, both will connect ok using the 32-bits client.

Comment: i wanted a 32 bit environment of visual studio but to use oracle 64 bit client .. how can i do that

Comment: @Peddireddy. You don't need a 64-bit client to connect to a 64-bit server. You DO need a client that is consistently either 32-bit or 64-bit though.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You cannot mix 32 and 64 bit applications in a .NET application on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get it to work. You need to install both versions on your development machine. The 32bit version is used during debugging and the 64bit version when you deploy or test the application without Visual Studio.